# Python setuptools install is not installing a package

Tags: python, setuptools

I created a fork from this git repo: https://github.com/QQuick/Opy

I added an `__init__.py` to the `opy` directory / package.  When I run `setup.py install`, the `opy` package is not installed into my `site-packages` directory.  Why?

Here's the setup.py script:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append ('opy')
import opy

from setuptools import setup
import codecs

def read (*paths):
    with codecs.open (os.path.join (*paths), 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as aFile:
        return aFile.read()

setup (
    name = 'Opy',
    version = opy.programVersion,
    description = 'OPY - Obfuscator for Python, string obfuscation added, keyword added',
    long_description = (
        read ('README.rst') + '\n\n' +
        read ('license_reference.txt')
    ),
    keywords = ['opy', 'obfuscator', 'obfuscation', 'obfuscate', 'kivy', 'pyo', 'python'],
    url = 'https://github.com/JdeH/Opy/',
    license = 'Apache 2',
    author = 'Jacques de Hooge',
    author_email = 'jacques.de.hooge@qquick.org',
    packages = ['opy'], 
    include_package_data = True,
    install_requires = [],
    classifiers = [
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: Other/Proprietary License',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ],
)
```

Output:

```
>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating Opy.egg-info
writing Opy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Opy.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Opy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'Opy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'Opy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.des' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'Opy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\opy
copying opy\opy.py -> build\lib\opy
copying opy\opymaster.py -> build\lib\opy
copying opy\__init__.py -> build\lib\opy
creating build\bdist.win32
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\opy
copying build\lib\opy\opy.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\opy
copying build\lib\opy\opymaster.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\opy
copying build\lib\opy\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\opy
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\opy\opy.py to opy.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\opy\opymaster.py to opymaster.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\opy\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying Opy.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying Opy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying Opy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying Opy.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist\Opy-1.1.28.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing Opy-1.1.28.1-py2.7.egg
Copying Opy-1.1.28.1-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding Opy 1.1.28.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\opy-1.1.28.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for Opy==1.1.28.1
Finished processing dependencies for Opy==1.1.28.1
```

Comment: What makes you think that the package is not installed? It's there, just not in the form you've expected it to be. Look for the file `opy-1.1.28.1-py2.7.egg` in the `site-packages` dir, this is the installed package. Also, to check whether the package is installed or not, you can try importing the modules: `python -c "import opy; print('opy is installed')"` etc.

Comment: Oh.  Really?  The egg is the package itself?  There is a way to make setuptools install it in clear text?

Comment: An egg is just a zip archive, so you can take a look of what's inside. You can force `setuptools` into flat install by issuing `python setup.py install --old-and-unmanageable` which is effectively (almost) the same as using `distutils.core.setup`, but it's named so by a reason.

Comment: Thing is, the `distutils` package doesn't track the files that are being installed for a package, so there is no way to perform a clean uninstall afterwards - you simply don't know what files belonging to the package should be removed. This is one of the main reasons `setuptools` rolled its own package installer `easy_install` and the `egg` format (package as a single file), also why `pip` emerged as the `setuptools` approach also failed (but that's another story).

Comment: Do you have to use `setup.py install` at all? The proper alternative for that is running `pip install .` from the dir where `setup.py` resides; `pip` builds a wheel from the sources, including the list of files in it and then installs that built wheel; afterwards, uninstalling the package is just going thru that list and deleting each file. Works like a charm.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  That helps a great deal!  Now that you bring it up, I recall that an egg is a zip.  I'l revert my fork back to the setuptools setup then.

Comment: Oh really?  You can use pip locally?  I always used pip like apt-get or yum, etc. to pull a remote repo.

Comment: The pip install worked! Fantastic!  You just taught me multiple useful nuggets here.  If you post your comment(s) as an answer I'll gladly upvote/mark as accepted.  I'd upvote a few times if I could!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sum up the statements from the comments:

`setuptools.setup` does its job; however, instead of just copying modules to `site-packages` (what `distutils` does), `python setup.py install` will build an egg file which is then installed by simply copying it to `site-packages`. This way, it's easy to uninstall the package afterwards by just removing the one egg file.

If you don't like the package being installed in an archive, you can:

- do the "old and unmanageable" install:

  ```
  $ python setup.py install --old-and-unmanageable
  ```

  but beware that you may not be able to properly uninstall the package when doing that. Still, this command may be used e.g. in a virtual environment that you plan to remove afterwards anyway;
- use `pip` as it's able to install packages from source directories:

  ```
  $ pip install dir/
  ```

  where `dir` is the directory containing the `setup.py` script. This is the preferred way; `pip` will build a wheel file first, then install it. The modules will be installed flat (written to disk as files), but `pip` will also store the list of installed files among other metadata, so all files will be removed properly on package uninstall.

Comment: It's surprising (misleading) how impotent the `python3 setup.py install` command is.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced

`from setuptools import setup`

with

`from distutils.core import setup`

and that worked.  But, isn't the `setuptools` module version of that function supposed to install into the site-packages directory?  The documentation indicates it does.  I don't get it...